# join data using Linq in asp.net

Tags: join, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a few data which I need to bind with the Result I am showing as a List.

I have to fetch data from 2 tables.

[image: Below is the Image which shows table from the 2 tables.]

Below is my code where I need to apply Linq to fetch data from both the tables:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var blogList = await _blogRepository.Query().Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(blogList);
    }
```

I want the Column ImageUrl result from table 2 joined to table 1. Also, I want to send the ImageURL in form of an array along with the data from Table 1 for further usage.

Comment: ASP.NET is a web framework, not a data access library. You are probably using EF Core or youw own classes on top of it? `Query()` isn't an EF Core function and there's no LINQ2SQL in .NET Core

Comment: As for joins, don't. It's the *ORM's* job to generate joins from the relations and navigation properties between entities. `Blog` for example should have an `Images` collection.